# fill in NA values for multiple columns in 1 df based on values from another df

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 dfs. There are NA values for 2 variables in 1 data frame that I want to replace with values in another df. Here is my sample data:

```
df1
id    Sex    Race     Income
1     M      White      1
2     NA     Hispanic   2
3     NA     NA         3
```

```
df2
id    Sex    Race
1     M      White
2     F      Hispanic
3     M      White
4     F      Black
```

I want the data to look like this where the NA values for df1 for sex and race are filled in by the values for df2.

```
df2
id    Sex    Race      Income
1     M      White       1
2     F      Hispanic    2
3     M      White       3
4     F      Black       NA
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a join alone `by` 'id' (based on the data you showed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base R option using `merge`

```
subset(
  merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.y = TRUE),
  select = c("id", "Sex.y", "Race.y", "Income")
)
```

which gives

```
  id Sex.y   Race.y Income
1  1     M    White      1
2  2     F Hispanic      2
3  3     M    White      3
4  4     F    Black     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a join here

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, Income := Income, on = .(id)]
```

-output

```
df2
#   id Sex     Race Income
#1:  1   M    White      1
#2:  2   F Hispanic      2
#3:  3   M    White      3
#4:  4   F    Black     NA
```

---

If we need to choose the 'Sex', 'Race' between the non-NA elements

```
nm1 <- names(df2)[-1]
setDT(df2)[df1, c(nm1, 'Income') := c(Map(fcoalesce, 
  .SD[, nm1, with = FALSE], mget(paste0('i.', nm1))), list(Income)), on = .(id)]
```

-output

```
df2
#   id Sex     Race Income
#1:  1   M    White      1
#2:  2   F Hispanic      2
#3:  3   M    White      3
#4:  4   F    Black     NA
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, with just `dplyr` functions

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = 'id') %>% 
  transmute(id,  Sex = coalesce(Sex.x, Sex.y),
                Race = coalesce(Race.x, Race.y),
           Income)
```

-output

```
#  id Sex     Race Income
#1  1   M    White      1
#2  2   F Hispanic      2
#3  3   M    White      3
#4  4   F    Black     NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, Sex = c("M", NA, NA), Race = c("White", 
"Hispanic", NA), Income = 1:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, Sex = c("M", "F", "M", "F"), Race = c("White", 
"Hispanic", "White", "Black")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` approach can be using a join after reshaping both dataframes to long (using the well known `pivot_longer()`) and then reshaping to wide (using `pivot_wider()`) to obtain the expected result. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(-id,~as.character(.))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  full_join(df1 %>% 
              mutate(across(-id,~as.character(.))) %>%
              pivot_longer(-id) %>% rename(value2=value)) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(is.na(value),value2,value)) %>% select(-value2) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  mutate(Income=as.numeric(Income))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id Sex   Race     Income
  <int> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 M     White         1
2     2 F     Hispanic      2
3     3 M     White         3
4     4 F     Black        NA
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, Sex = c("M", NA, NA), Race = c("White", 
"Hispanic", NA), Income = 1:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#Data 2
df2 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, Sex = c("M", "F", "M", "F"), Race = c("White", 
"Hispanic", "White", "Black")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```